# solutions needed to fill datagrid via class through select store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, vb.net-2010

Situation:

Form - contains dataGridView ( need to be populated )

Class - should contain all the process of filling

what i am doing in class?

```vb
 Public Function prodcatgetdata(ByVal cmd As String) As DataTable
    Try

        Dim command As New SqlCommand(cmd)
        Dim dsprodcat As New DataSet
        Dim cn1 As New SqlConnection("data source =SC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=mydb;integrated security=true")
        Dim daprodcat As New SqlDataAdapter(selectprodcat, cn1)
        cn1.Open()
        'daprodcat.SelectCommand = cmd
        daprodcat.Fill(dsprodcat)
        Return dsprodcat.Tables("m_prodcat")
        cn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```

what i am doing in formload() ?

```vb
prodcatcls.prodcatgetdata(selectprodcat)
```

where i am going wrong ?

Comment: What is exactly the problem?

Comment: i want to populate datagrid in form through a class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just declare a DataTable and fill it with the prodcatgetdata function like this

```
Dim DataTable1 As DataTable = prodcatcls.prodcatgetdata(selectprodcat)
```

then, to bind it to the DataGridView, add the following

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = DataTable1
```